# android openGL Es 2 showing no image

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, texture2d

I am new to Android's OpenGL ES. I have spent 3 days in texture mapping but did not get any solution to my problem. Now I have written some code but it's only showing the background color but not the image that I want to show on the surface. Here is the `myRenderer` class constructor

```
public myRenderer()
{

    imageBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.context.getResources(),R.drawable.image);

    float texture[]={

            0.0f, 0.0f, //bottom-left
            0.1f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
            0.0f, 0.1f, // top-left
            0.1f, 0.1f  // top-right
            };

    float vertex[]={
             0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //3 Vertex Coords, 3 RGB Vals
             1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //3 Vertex Coords, 3 RGB Vals
             0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //3 Vertex Coords, 3 RGB Vals
             0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //3 Vertex Coords, 3 RGB Vals
             1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //3 Vertex Coords, 3 RGB Vals
             1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //3 Vertex Coords, 3 RGB Vals

             };




    float triagnle2[]={

            -0.75f,0.5f,0.0f,
            0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,

            0.75f,0.5f,0.0f,
            1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,

            0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
            1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f

    };

    byte[] indices={

            0,1,2, 3,4,5//Front Face

    };
    vertexBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertex.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertex).position(0);

    textureBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture).position(0);

    indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.position(0);
}
```

Here is what's in SurfaceCreated:

```
    GLES20.glClearColor(1.7f,1.5f,0.5f,0.5f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    //imageBitmap.getPixels(pixels,0,imageBitmap.getWidth(),0,0,imageBitmap.getWidth(),imageBitmap.getHeight());
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, imageBitmap, 0);
    imageBitmap.recycle();


    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LESS);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix,0);

        final float eyeX = 0.0f;
        final float eyeY = 0.0f;
        final float eyeZ = 2.5f;

        // We are looking toward the distance
        final float lookX = 0.0f;
        final float lookY = 0.0f;
        final float lookZ = 1f;

        // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we holding the camera.
        final float upX = 0.0f;
        final float upY = 1.0f;
        final float upZ = 0.0f;

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);


        final String vertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.

          + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
          + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"     // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.

          + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
         +"attribute vec2 TextureCoord;"

         +"varying vec2 TextureCoordOut;"
          + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our vertex shader.
          + "{                              \n"
        //  + "   v_Color = a_Color;          \n"     // Pass the color through to the fragment shader.
          +"TextureCoordOut = TextureCoord;"                                          // It will be interpolated across the triangle.
          + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"     // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
          + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in
          + "}                              \n";


        final String fragmentShader =
            "precision mediump float;       \n"     // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a

            +"varying mediump vec2 TextureCoordOut;"
        +"uniform sampler2D Sampler;// precision in the fragment shader."

          //+ "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the
                                                    // triangle per fragment.
          + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our fragment shader.
          + "{                              \n"
          + "   gl_FragColor =  vec4(texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut).xyz, 0.5);    \n"     // Pass the color directly through the pipeline.
          + "}                              \n";
        int vertexShederHandle=GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        if(vertexShederHandle!=0)
        {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShederHandle, vertexShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShederHandle);

            int[] compileStatus=new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShederHandle,GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS,compileStatus,0);
            if(compileStatus[0]==0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShederHandle);
                vertexShederHandle=0;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating Sheder");
        }



        /////////////

        int fragmentShederHandle=GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if(fragmentShederHandle!=0)
        {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShederHandle,fragmentShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShederHandle);

            int[] compileStatus=new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShederHandle,GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS,compileStatus,0);
            if(compileStatus[0]==0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShederHandle);
                fragmentShederHandle=0;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating Sheder");
        }

        int progameHandle=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        if(progameHandle!=0)
        {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(progameHandle, vertexShederHandle);
            GLES20.glAttachShader(progameHandle, fragmentShederHandle);

            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(progameHandle, 0, "a_Position");
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(progameHandle, 1, "a_Color");

            GLES20.glLinkProgram(progameHandle);

            int[] linkStatus=new int[1];

            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(progameHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS,linkStatus,0);
            if(linkStatus[0]==0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(progameHandle);
                progameHandle=0;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating programe");
        }

        mMVPMatrixHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(progameHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
        mPositionHandle=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(progameHandle, "a_Position");
        mColorHandle=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(progameHandle, "a_Color");

        GLES20.glUseProgram(progameHandle);
```

Here is OnSurfaceChanged:

```
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
    // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 0.4f;
    final float far = 10.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
```

And here is onDrawFrame:

```
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ENABLED);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0+textures[0]);
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,6,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,indexBuffer);
```

forgive me if doing some stupidity..
please tell me what to do.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're intending this call to do: `GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ENABLED)`, but that's not a legal target to glEnable and is almost certainly generating a gl error.

Put some glGetError throughout your code and try to find the lines that might be causing you errors, and if you have no errors, please update the question with that fact so we know what else to look for.